# Restored Tensorflow model always outputs same prediction unless input is flipped

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

My restored Tensorflow image classifier outputs the same prediction for all inputs unless I use OpenCV to flip the image and pass both the original and its mirror to the model at the same time. Passing just one or the other results in the same prediction. Why is this happening?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Import restored Tensorflow model
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_file_path)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
make_logits = graph.get_operation_by_name("logits")
logits = make_logits.outputs[0]

image = np.random.rand(240, 320, 3)
flipped = cv2.flip(random_image, 1)

print(logits.eval(feed_dict={x: [image]}, session=sess))
# result: [[-0.0784276   0.40849224  0.01139636]]

print(logits.eval(feed_dict={x: [image,flipped]}, session=sess))
# result: [[ 2.49520946  2.34099054 -3.41013908]
#          [-2.6520648  -1.52400601  3.43293166]]

print(logits.eval(feed_dict={x: [flipped]}, session=sess))
# result: [[-0.0784276   0.40849224  0.01139636]]
```

The model has great accuracy, and I have a balanced dataset, so it's not simply predicting the majority class every time. Training and test error both decrease over time, so I believe the fitting process is ok. For what it's worth, I augmented my training dataset by flipping images (and their labels as well), but I don't see why this would make a difference.

The ugly hack/fix for this is to always feed the image-mirror pair and then only take the original's result and discard the mirror's result. When I do this the model has high accuracy, but the solution feels ridiculous.

Comment: maybe you should try setting different seeds for your random image, otherwise it might be that always the same image is generated and predicted; not sure if this is the real problem, since you say "all inputs".

Comment: @Zephro. It produces the same output even for real images too. I created a random image to make my question's code more concise.

Comment: Can you try `print(logits.eval(feed_dict={x: [image,image]}, session=sess))` and `print(logits.eval(feed_dict={x: [flipped,flipped]}, session=sess))`?

Comment: @Mingxing Both result in [-0.0784276   0.40849224  0.01139636]]
[[-0.0784276   0.40849224  0.01139636]], which is the same constant prediction as before

Comment: This is weird. Since you are loading the model from a checkpoint, it is hard to debug. Is it possible to provide a minimal python model to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes, it's very weird. I've been trying to figure this out for nearly a month. I'll try training a simple GLM on random images and see if the issue persists.